# Laravel 6 barryvdh / laravel-dompdf rendering issues

Tags: dompdf, laravel-6.2

I recently upgraded my Laravel project from 5.6 to Laravel 6.2, I also upgraded the dompdf package from 0.8.3 to 0.8.5. Now my PDF's are rendering incorrectly, they were rendered correctly in the previous version of Laravel and dompdf. I did upgrade to Laravel 5.8 before going to 6 but I did not test the PDF's. I use HTML tables for my formatting and inline CSS.

In the PDF the tables are getting cut off, the right hand side runs off the page. The emails are rendering correctly.

I tried downgrading the dompdf version from 0.8.5 back to 0.8.3 but the issue remains. I'm not entirely sure what I need to change to get it to render correctly. I have a couple other PDF's and they are all doing the same thing, even the ones set to portrait. The code below is set to landscape but it is ignoring that and rendering in portrait.

Thanks in advance for reading this super long post, any help or constructive criticism is welcome!

Here is the controller code:

```
/**
 * email rental agreement (formats the email as the rental agreement and attaches a pdf)
 * 
 * @param Request $request
 * @param RentalAgreement $rentalAgreement
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function email(Request $request, RentalAgreement $rentalAgreement)
{
    $email_message = $request->email_message;
    $email_subject = $request->email_subject;
    $email_header = $headers = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';

    $address = $rentalAgreement->customer()->getDefaultAddress()->get()->first();

    $array = $rentalAgreement->createEmailItems();
    $rental = $array['rental'];
    $details =  $array['details'];
    $company_phone =  $array['company_phone'];
    $contact_phone =  $array['contact_phone'];

    $emails = array_column(CustomerContactEmail::select('email')->whereIn('id', $request->email)
                                               ->get()->toArray(), 'email');

    if (count((array)$emails) > 0) {
        Mail::to($emails)->cc($rental->company_email)
                         ->send(new RentalAgreementMail($address, $company_phone, $contact_phone, $rental, $details, 
                                                        $email_message, $email_subject), $email_header);
        $alert = 'Email sent.';
    } else {
        $alert = 'Unable to send email. Rental Agreement Contact has no email addresses. '
                .'Assign email for contact to send email.';
    }

    return redirect()->action('RentalAgreementController@edit', ['rentalAgreement' => $rentalAgreement, 
                                                                 'customer' => $rentalAgreement->customer])
                     ->with('alert', $alert);
}
```

The Mail code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use PDF;

class RentalAgreementMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $address;
    public $company_phone;
    public $contact_phone;
    public $details;
    public $email_message;
    public $email_subject;
    public $rental;
    protected $pdf_file;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($address, $company_phone, $contact_phone, $rental, $details, $email_message, $email_subject)
    {
        $this->address = $address;
        $this->company_phone = $company_phone;
        $this->contact_phone = $contact_phone;
        $this->rental = $rental;
        $this->details = $details;
        $this->email_message = $email_message;
        $this->email_subject = '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode($email_subject).'?=';

        $this->pdf_file = PDF::loadView('emails.rental_agreement', ['address' => $address, 
                                                                    'company_phone' => $company_phone, 
                                                                    'contact_phone' => $contact_phone,  
                                                                    'rental' => $rental, 'details' => $details])
                             ->setPaper('letter', 'landscape')->stream();
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $title = $this->rental->customer_name.' '.$this->rental->type_name;
        $title .= ' '.$this->rental->job_name;
        $title .= !empty($this->rental->effective_date) ? ' '.$this->rental->effective_date->format('m-d-Y') : '';

        return $this->from($this->rental->company_email, $this->rental->company_name)
                    ->subject($this->email_subject)->view('emails.rental_agreement')
                    ->attachData($this->pdf_file, $title.'.pdf', [
                                 'mime' => 'application/pdf',
                        ]);
    }
}
```

The HTML code (issue is in the 3rd table tag):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=1'>
        <title>{{ $rental->customer_name.' '.$rental->type_name }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @if (isset($email_message))
            {!! nl2br(htmlspecialchars($email_message)) !!}
        @endif

        <table style='width: 100%; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 1px; margin: 0 0 5px 0;'>
            <tbody>
                <tr style='padding: 0;'>
                    <td style='width: 70%; padding: 0; margin: 0;'>
                        @if (!empty($rental->logo_path))
                            <!--img src="{{ asset($rental->logo_path) }}" height=125 style='margin: 0; padding: 0; display: block;' alt='logo' title='logo'/-->
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    <td colspan=2 style='width: 30%; padding: 0; text-align: center;'>
                        <h2 style='color: #4D6F6F; padding-top: 20px;'>{{ $rental->type_name }}</h2>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style='padding: 3px;'>
                    <td style='width: 70%; padding: 1px;'>{{ $rental->company_address }}</td>
                    <td style='width: 15%; font-weight: bold; padding: 1px;'>Job:</td>
                    <td style='width: 15%; padding: 1px;'>{{ $rental->job_name }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style='padding: 1px;'>
                    <td style='width: 70%; padding: 1px;'>{{ $rental->company_city.', '.$rental->company_state.' '.$rental->company_zip }}</td>
                    <td style='width: 15%; font-weight: bold; padding: 1px;'>Effective:</td>
                    <td style='width: 15%; padding: 1px;'>
                        {{ !empty($rental->effective_date) ? $rental->effective_date->format('m/d/Y') : '' }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style='padding: 1px;'>
                    <td style='width: 70%; padding: 1px;'>{{ $company_phone }}</td>
                    <td style='width: 15%; font-weight: bold; padding: 1px;'>End:</td>
                    <td style='width: 15%; padding: 1px;'>
                        {{ !empty($rental->end_date) ? $rental->end_date->format('m/d/Y') : '' }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style='padding: 1px;'>
                    <td style='width: 70%; padding: 1px;'>{{ $rental->company_email }}</td>
                    <td style='width: 15%; padding: 1px;'></td>
                    <td style='width: 15%; padding: 1px;'></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <table style='border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 1px; margin: 10px 0; padding-top: 15px; margin: auto; width: 97%;'>
            <tbody>
                <tr style='padding: 1px;'>
                    <td style='width: 70%; font-weight: bold; padding: 1px;'>
                        <h3 style='margin: 0; font-weight: bold;'>To: {{ $rental->customer_name }}</h3>
                    </td>
                    <td style='width: 15%; font-weight: bold; padding: 1px;'>
                        {{ empty($rental->po_number) ? '' : 'PO #:' }}
                    </td>
                    <td style='width: 15%; padding: 1px;'>
                        {{ empty($rental->po_number) ? '' : $rental->po_number }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style='padding: 1px;'>
                    <td style='width: 70%; padding: 1px;'>
                        {{ $rental->contact_name.' '.$contact_phone }}
                    </td>
                    <td style='width: 15%; font-weight: bold; padding: 1px;'>Account #:</td>
                    <td style='width: 15%; padding: 1px;'>{{ $rental->customer_account_number }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style='padding: 1px;'>
                    <td style='width: 70%; padding: 1px;'>{{ isset($address) ? $address->address : '' }}</td>
                    <td style='width: 15%; font-weight: bold; padding: 1px;'>{{ empty($rental->ship_name) ? '' : 'Ship:' }}</td>
                    <td style='width: 15%; padding: 1px;'>
                        {{ empty($rental->ship_name) ? '' : $rental->ship_name }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @if (!empty($address) && !empty($address->address2))
                    <tr style='padding: 1px;'>
                        <td style='width: 70%; padding: 1px;'>{{ $address->address2 }}</td>
                        <td style='width: 15%; padding: 1px;'></td>
                        <td style='width: 15%; padding: 1px;'></td>
                    </tr>
                @endif
                <tr style='padding: 1px;'>
                    <td style='width: 70%; padding: 1px;'>
                        {{ isset($address) ? ($address->city.', '.$address->state.' '.$address->zip) : '' }}
                    </td>
                    <td style='width: 15%; font-weight: bold; padding: 1px;'>Term:</td>
                    <td style='width: 15%; padding: 1px;'>{{ $rental->net_term }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <table style='width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 1px; margin: 15px 0 0 0; border-bottom: 2pt solid #4D6F6F;'>
            <thead style='border-bottom: 2pt solid #4D6F6F;'>
                <tr style='padding: 1px; font-size: .90em; color: #005187;'>
                    <th style='width: 5%; padding: 3px; text-align: center;'>#</th>
                    <th style='width: 5%; padding: 3px; text-align: center;'>Qty</th>
                    <th style='width: 75%; padding: 3px; text-align: center;'>
                        <table style='width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 1px; margin: 0 0 0 0;'>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style='width: 50%; padding: 3px;'>Description</th>
                                    <th colspan=2 style='width: 30%; padding: 3px; text-align: center;'>Duration</th>
                                    <th style='width: 20%; padding: 3px; text-align: center;'>Price</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </th>
                    <th style='width: 15%; padding: 3px; text-align: center;'>Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($details as $detail)
                    <tr style='padding: 1px; font-size: .90em;'>
                        <td style='width: 5%; border-bottom: 1pt solid #4D6F6F; padding: 3px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top;'>
                            {{ number_format($detail->line_number, 0, '.', ',') }}
                        </td>
                        <td style='width: 5%; border-bottom: 1pt solid #4D6F6F; padding: 3px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top;'>
                            {{ number_format($detail->quantity, 0, '.', ',') }}
                        </td>
                        <td style='width: 75%; border-bottom: 1pt solid #4D6F6F; padding: 3px; vertical-align: top;'>
                            <table style='width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 1px; margin: 0 0 0 0;'>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr style='padding: 1px;'>
                                        <td style='width: 50%; padding: 3px;'>{{ $detail->item_description }}</td>
                                        <td style='width: 15%; padding: 3px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top;'>
                                            {{ !empty($detail->billing_start_date) ? $detail->billing_start_date->format('m/d/Y') : '' }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td style='width: 15%; padding: 3px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top;'>
                                            {{ !empty($detail->billing_end_date) ? $detail->billing_end_date->format('m/d/Y') : '' }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td style='width: 20%; padding: 3px; text-align: right; vertical-align: top;'>
                                            {{ number_format($detail->item_price, 2, '.', ',') }}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    @if (count($detail->itemTypeAccessories) > 0)
                                        <tr  style='padding: 1px; color: #005187;'>
                                            <td style='width: 50%; border-bottom: 1pt solid #C0CAD3; padding: 3px; vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold;'>
                                                Accessories
                                            </td>
                                            <td colspan=3 style='width: 50%; padding: 3px;'></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr style='padding: 1px;'>
                                            <td style='width: 50%; padding: 3px; vertical-align: top;'>
                                                {{ implode(', ', $detail->itemTypeAccessories->map(function ($item, $key) { return $item->name;})->toArray()) }}
                                            </td>
                                            <td colspan=2 style='width: 30%; padding: 3px;'></td>
                                            <td style='width: 20%; padding: 3px; text-align: right; vertical-align: top;'>
                                                <?php $accessory_price = 0; ?>

                                                @foreach($detail->itemTypeAccessories as $accessory)
                                                    <?php $accessory_price += $accessory->pivot->price; ?>
                                                @endforeach

                                                {{ number_format($accessory_price, 2, '.', ',') }}
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endif

                                    @if (count($detail->itemTypeServices) > 0)
                                        <tr  style='padding: 1px; color: #005187;'>
                                            <td style='width: 50%; border-bottom: 1pt solid #C0CAD3; padding: 3px; vertical-align: top; font-weight: bold;'>
                                                Services
                                            </td>
                                            <td colspan=3 style='width: 50%; padding: 3px;'></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        @foreach ($detail->itemTypeServices as $service)
                                            <tr style='padding: 1px;'>
                                                <td style='width: 50%; padding: 3px; vertical-align: top;'>
                                                    {{ $service->name }}
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='width: 15%; padding: 3px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top;'>
                                                    {{ empty($service->pivot->delivery_date) ? '' : ' '.$service->pivot->delivery_date->format('m/d/Y') }}
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='width: 15%; padding: 3px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top;'>
                                                    {{ empty($service->pivot->pickup_date) ? '' : $service->pivot->pickup_date->format('m/d/Y') }}
                                                </td>
                                                <td style='width: 20%; padding: 3px; text-align: right; vertical-align: top;'>
                                                    {{ number_format((float)$service->pivot->delivery_price + (float)$service->pivot->pickup_price, 2, '.', ',') }}
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                    @endif
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td style='width: 15%; border-bottom: 1pt solid #4D6F6F; padding: 3px; text-align: right; vertical-align: top;'>
                            {{ number_format($detail->subtotal, 2, '.', ',') }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <table style='width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 1px; margin: 0;'>
            <tbody>
                <tr style='padding: 1px; font-size: .90em; font-weight: bold;'>
                    <th style='width: 5%; padding: 3px;'>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th style='width: 5%; padding: 3px;'>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th style='width: 75%; padding: 3px;'>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th style='width: 15%; padding: 3px;'>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
                <tr style='padding: 1px; font-size: .90em; font-weight: bold;'>
                    <td colspan=2 style='width: 10%; padding: 3px;'></td>
                    <td style='width: 75%; padding: 3px; text-align: right;'>Subtotal&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style='width: 15%; padding: 3px; text-align: right;'>
                        {{ number_format($rental->subtotal, 2, '.', ',') }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style='padding: 1px; font-size: .90em; font-weight: bold;'>
                    <td colspan=2 style='width: 10%; padding: 3px;'></td>
                    <td style='width: 75%; padding: 3px; text-align: right;'>Tax&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td style='width: 15%; padding: 3px; text-align: right;'>
                        {{ number_format($rental->tax_amount, 2, '.', ',') }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr style='padding: 1px; font-size: .90em; font-weight: bold;'>
                    <td colspan=2 style='width: 10%; padding: 3px;'></td>
                    <td style='width: 75%; padding: 3px; text-align: right;'>
                        Total&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td style='width: 15%; border-top: 2pt solid #4D6F6F; padding: 3px; text-align: right;'>
                        {{ number_format($rental->total, 2, '.', ',') }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <?php $terms_count = 0; ?>

        @if (!empty($rental->purchase_order_terms))
            <p style='font-size: .90em; font-weight: bold;'>PO Terms:</p>
            <p style='font-size: .90em;'>{!! nl2br(e($rental->purchase_order_terms)) !!}</p>

            <?php $terms_count += 1;?>
        @endif

        @if (!empty($rental->customer_terms_conditions))
            @if ($terms_count == 0)
                <p style='font-size: .90em; font-weight: bold;'>
            @else
                <p style='font-size: .90em; font-weight: bold; border-top: 1pt solid #4D6F6F;'>
            @endif

            Customer Terms:</p>
            <p style='font-size: .90em;'>{!! nl2br(e($rental->customer_terms_conditions)) !!}</p>

            <?php $terms_count += 1;?>
        @endif

        @if (!empty($rental->rental_agreement_terms))
            @if ($terms_count == 0)
                <p style='font-size: .90em; font-weight: bold;'>
            @else
                <p style='font-size: .90em; font-weight: bold; border-top: 1pt solid #4D6F6F;'>
            @endif

            Rental Terms:</p>
            <p style='font-size: .90em;'>{!! nl2br(e($rental->rental_agreement_terms)) !!}</p>

            <?php $terms_count += 1;?>
        @endif

        @if (!empty($rental->notes))
            @if ($terms_count == 0)
                <p style='font-size: .90em; font-weight: bold;'>
            @else
                <p style='font-size: .90em; font-weight: bold; border-top: 1pt solid #4D6F6F;'>
            @endif

            Notes:</p>
                <p style='font-size: .90em;'>{!! nl2br(e($rental->notes)) !!}</p>

            <?php $terms_count += 1;?>
        @endif

        <table style='width: 97%; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 1px; margin: 15px 0; margin: auto;'>
            <tbody>
                <tr rowspan=2 style='padding: 3px;'>
                    <td colspan=3 style='width: 60%; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px;'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style='padding: 3px;'>
                    <td style='width: 10%; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px; text-align: right;'>
                        Customer Signature:
                    </td>
                    <td style='width: 40%; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px; border-bottom: 1pt solid #4D6F6F;'></td>
                    <td style='width: 10%; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px;'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style='padding: 3px;'>
                    <td colspan=3 style='width: 60%; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px; text-align: center;'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style='padding: 3px;'>
                    <td colspan=3 style='width: 60%; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px; text-align: center;'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style='padding: 3px;'>
                    <td colspan=3 style='width: 60%; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px; text-align: center;'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr style='padding: 3px;'>
                    <td colspan=3 style='width: 60%; font-weight: bold; padding: 3px; text-align: center;'>
                        We appreciate your business.
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the email: 
[image]

Here is the PDF:
[image]